# CardStyleInterpolators inside setOptions in React Navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to change the transition style based on where the request comes from. Can I do something like that?

```
navigation.setOptions({
    CardStyleInterpolator: ({ CardStyleInterpolators }) => {
      if (route.params?.cleanup == 1) {
        CardStyleInterpolators.forVerticalIOS;
      } else {
        CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS;
      }
    },
}}
```